# Difference between _process(delta) and _physics_process(delta)?

Tags: godot, physics-engine

The documentation is pointing one main difference, this is the concept of being synced or not with the physics engine, so the `delta` parameter has more chance to be constant in `_physics_process(delta)` than in `_process(delta)`.

But I am pretty sure that no one counts on that. And that everybody checks the value of delta in `_physics_process(delta)`.

So what are the different use cases of those two functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I made an more in depth explanation on GitHub: [link](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/discussions/4937#discussioncomment-3198281).*

---

### Graphics or Physics

One difference is that `_process` is tied to graphics (it runs once per frame), while `_physics_process` isn't. As such, VSync (which is on by default) will affect `_process`, depending on the monitor frame rate, of course. Use it for anything graphics related.

The other is that `_physics_process` is tied to the physics, while `_process` isn't. As such, Physics FPS (which is 60 by default) will be the target frame rate for `_physics_process`. Godot will call `_physics_process` before computing physics response,  and thus to get that correct physics response, use `_physics_process` for anything physics related.

If your script need to read any properties that the physics server will update (e.g position, ray casts), then avoid reading them in `_process`. See [Physics process callback](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.3/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html#physics-process-callback).

Is moving a node graphics or physics? If it is a [`PhysicsBody`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsbody.html) or [`PhysicsBody2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsbody2d.html) consider it physics (corollary: use `_physics_process` to move `KinematicBody` and its 2D counterpart). Otherwise, it is graphics.

---

What if you need to compute something with a stable frequency, but it does not affect physics, nor graphics? Well, it is neither. While it is often harmless to hijack either `_process` or `_physics_process`, consider using a [`Timer`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_timer.html) (or a coroutine, or a [`Thread`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_thread.html) with a good old loop).

---

By the way, you can disable using [`set_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.3/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-set-process) and [`set_physics_process`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.3/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-set-physics-process).

---

### Input

For input, I would make the same distinction as for anything else. Should the input update graphics (e.g. it is a `Control`)? then either `_input` or `_process`. Should input update physics? then either `_input` or `_physics_process`.

I'd prefer using `Input` from `_process` or `_physics_process`, until you run into a situation where you need `_input`.

By the way, the `just_pressed` and `just_released` methods are intended to work on both `_process` and `_physics_process`, they check on which one you are calling them.

---

### On smooth motion

Either `_process` or `_physics_process` could be the faster one, depending on hardware and configuration. Any visual only change that happens faster than `_process` will not be seen. On the other hand, if it changes any slower, then it will not appear as smooth motion.

Since Godot will execute physics according to Physics FPS, if you configure a low Physics FPS, the physic bodies appear to teleport. Plus, tunneling will be more likely to happen. For which you want to configure your `RigidBody` to use continuous collision detection (set it to Cast Ray, because shape Cast Shape is not great on the current version - *note: I wrote this referring to Godot 3.x*).

It is possible to apply smooth motion to sprites and meshes (moving them in `_process`) to follow physic bodies (which move in `_physics_process`), see also [smoothing-addon](https://github.com/lawnjelly/smoothing-addon). You may see shapes intersect because it does not predict collisions. *But that might be the price for better performance.*

*You might also be interested in the proposal [Fixing physics timestep vs refresh rate problems (jitter)](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/1936), and the proposal [Add object position interpolation between physics frames](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/671)*

---

### On delta

Godot will try to keep stable the frequency of both `_physics_process` and `_process` (when VSync is enabled). However, that is not certain. Not on a machine where there are other applications running, or where you can write a code that takes too much time to run for the time budget of a frame. And thus, both need and have `delta`.

There are some things that will not require you to use `delta`. For example, for graphics if you use an `AnimationPlayer` or `Tween`, it is handled for you. *Of course, `AnimationPlayer` or `Tween` are not only useful for graphics.*

Similarly, for physics if you use `force` and `torque` methods of `RigidBody` and its 2D counterparts, you don't have to worry about `delta`.

And then on `KinematicBody` and its 2D counterpart, `move_and_slide` automatically applies `delta`, but `move_and_collide` and `test_motion` doesn't. Notice that `move_and_collide` and `test_motion` take `rel_vec` not `linear_velocity`. Thus, you should multiply by `delta` from `_physics_process` for them to be frame independent. Which is another reason to use them in `_physics_process`.